# Nginx reverse proxy uwsgi django intermittent 502

Tags: django, nginx, proxy, uwsgi

I have a site setup with Nginx as load balancer (least_conn) that uses a seperate uwsgi/django server as its upstream. This is normally a pool of about 5 uwsgi/django servers but I've limited it to just one to make sure it's not a bad server.

Under 'normal' user behavior, everything appears to be working fine. 
My problem is that rapid, successive requests will intermittently generate a 502 error. I can recreate this with a few tries by opening a page in our admin that contains a list to all the articles. By opening a bunch of the links in new tabs, about 1 in 10 will fail with a 502 error.

Another curiosity, the 502s happen very quickly when they do happen. For example, when a 502 does show up it's as instantaneous as the tab opening.  Where I would expect the nginx frontend to wait a bit before coming back with an error.

I'm using uwsgi_pass to directly proxy between the nginx load balancer and uwsgi. I've read in a number of other posts about having to increase buffers. I've tried setting uwsgi_buffers_size 16k; and uwsgi_buffers 4 16k; but they have not made a difference.

Error logs from both Nginx and Uwsgi don't show anything about the 502s. Google webmaster tools, does, however notice them.

Relevant nginx.conf settings:

```
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  logs/error.log;
error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
error_log  logs/error.log  info;

events {
    multi_accept on;
    use epoll;
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  off;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;



    #Timeouts
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    send_timeout 60;
    client_body_timeout 12;
    client_header_timeout 12;

    upstream backend {
    least_conn;
    server ipaddress:22882;
    }

    server {
        listen       27313;
        server_name  exampledomain.com;


        access_log  off;

        port_in_redirect off;

        uwsgi_next_upstream error;

        location / {
            uwsgi_read_timeout 300;
            uwsgi_send_timeout 150;
            uwsgi_connect_timeout 300;
            uwsgi_buffer_size 16k;
            uwsgi_buffers 4 16k;
            uwsgi_pass backend;
        }
```

Uwsgi started with these parameters:

```
--socket :22882 
--master 
--workers 5 
--threads 2 
--max-requests 1500 
--wsgi-file ~/django_prod/wsgi.py 
--pidfile ~/django_prod/nginx/log/uwsgi.pid 
--daemonize ~/django_prod/nginx/log/uwsgi.log 
--python-path ~/django_prod 
--python-path ~/django_prod/lib/ 
--env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings 
--vacuum
```

Comment: Note, that error 502 is different from 504. It is not "gateway timeout", it is "gateway error", so the real reason is on django side.

I assume that when worker limit is exceeded, django throws the 502 error on subsequent rewuests, but I don't know django good enough to be sure.

Comment: I'm seeing that when a page 502s, the corresponding entry in UWSGI's log appears normal, like any other working request. 

I know this entry is the page that errored with a 502 based on the time and the fact that this is a very old article that would not usually be accessed.

[pid: 3226|app: 0|req: 565/2827] 127.0.0.1 () {68 vars in 1628 bytes} [Tue Oct 25 10:55:02 2016] GET /admin/news/news/149/?_changelist_filters=p%3D218 => generated 13862 bytes in 92 msecs (HTTP/1.0 200) 6 headers in 307 bytes (1 switches on core 0)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I can eliminate the errors by disabling the pagespeed module for nginx.

I'm using pagespeed on the reverse proxy / load balancer provided by nginx. When I turn pagespeed off I'm no longer able to reproduce the intermittent 502s. Leaving this here in case anyone else has this problem.

Going to followup on the pagespeed discussion group and I'll update this post if I find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where under load, I start to get 502's back from uWSGI, and responses can come back with a 502 immediately.

Here are some things you can do

- Increase the uWSGI listen queue by setting `--listen` and [setting sysctl net.core.somaxconn](https://serverfault.com/questions/518862/will-increasing-net-core-somaxconn-make-a-difference) to an equal or higher value
- Make sure that you are on the latest uWSGI. There were a lot of bug fixes released in 2.0.x
- Check that you are on `HTTP/1.1`, and if so, use `--http11-socket`. This helps to ensures a persistent connection is established.

[uWSGItop](https://github.com/xrmx/uwsgitop) is really helpful to isolate the root cause of the issue, eg if CPU is low and the listen queue is high, then uWSGI is misbehaving.

Here are some more helpful ideas: https://wontonst.blogspot.com/2019/06/squishing-performance-bug-in.html